# Minkowski Sum of 3D(+) convex polygons

Tags: python, computational-geometry, point-in-polygon, convex-polygon

My goal is to obtain the representations of all faces (in the form of A[x,y,z]'>b) of a polyhedron that is the result of the convex difference between two convex polyhedra. Meaning, finding the intersection of all planes that are the result of the Minkowski difference of P1 - P2  = { x - y | x \in P1, y \in P2 }.

I'm looking for either an established library (Python?) or an idea on how to do this efficiently. I thought about doing something similar to the [GJK algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm) but I need all of the faces, and not just compute whether the origin is inside quickly. Moreover, seems inefficient to use this support function in a methodological way in 3D, or higher dimensions. Also, let's say I got the vertices, do I now need to form the plane equation from two vectors on it with the cross product, for every face, or is there a way to obtain it from the Minkowski sum itself? (keeping in mind the need for higher dimensions).

Comment: This appears to be a math question.

Comment: Hint: the Minkowski sum (or difference) is the convex hull of the points obtained by replicating the vertices of one polyhedron around every vertex of the other. So you can obtain it with a 3D hull algorithm such as QuickHull. This immediately generalizes to higher dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @YvesDaoust but it seems that finding the convexhull operation is difficult and won't scale well, especially when there are a lot of vertices. I posted an answer with what I finally came up with.

Comment: @GuyS: not more difficult nor not-scaling-well than the half space approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it seems I was finally able to solve it, and I'm posting in case it would interest anyone in the future:

First, I pip installed the [pypoman library](https://scaron.info/doc/pypoman).
With it, we are able to move easily between vertices and faces with `compute_polytope_halfspaces` (aka, the H-representation of a polytope). So I get the representation P_i: H_i x < h_i for i=1,2 from the vertices (or skip it if it's already in the correct format).

Now  if we set P_sum = {[x1;x2] \in R^2n | [H_1 0; 0 H_2] [x1;x2]' < [h_1,h_2]'}, notice that the Minkowski sum is equivalent to P1+P2 = [I,I] P_sum (idea from this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.05214.pdf) IV.B). So I can use pypoman's `project_polytope` function to get the Minkwoski sum with H_sum x < h_sum in the original dimensions.